# How to load admob interstitial ad before screen content flutter

Tags: android, flutter

Hi I want to display my interstitial ad after loading screen and before home screen
,

Right now after loading screen I get home screen content then after 3or4 seconds (depending on internet speed) I see interstitial ad.

So I want loading screen delay till interstitial ad full loaded and display after loading screen, When I close ad I can see Home screen

This is my **home screen** code and it contain interstitial ad code

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:firebase_admob/firebase_admob.dart';

class MainHome extends StatefulWidget {
  final dPWeather;

  MainHome({this.dPWeather});

  @override
  _MainHomeState createState() => _MainHomeState();
}

class _MainHomeState extends State<MainHome> {
  BannerAd firstBanner;
  InterstitialAd firstInetrs;
  double bannerHeight; ////////  Container height if there is no Ads

  BannerAd buildFirstBanner() {
    return BannerAd(
        adUnitId: 'ca-app-pub-0000000000000000000000000000',
        size: AdSize.fullBanner,
        listener: (MobileAdEvent event) {
          ////////  Container height if there is Ads or Not
          if (event == MobileAdEvent.loaded) {
            firstBanner..show();

            setState(() {
              bannerHeight = 50;
            });
          } else if (event == MobileAdEvent.failedToLoad) {
            setState(() {
              bannerHeight = 0;
            });
          }
          /////////////////////////////////////
        });
  }

  InterstitialAd buildFirstInters() {
    return InterstitialAd(
        adUnitId: 'ca-app-pub-11111111111111111111111111',
        listener: (MobileAdEvent event) {
          firstInetrs..show();
        });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    bannerHeight = 0; ////////  Container height if there is no Ads
    firstBanner = buildFirstBanner()..load(); /////// Banner AdMob
    firstInetrs = buildFirstInters()..load(); ////// Fullscreen AdMob
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
      drawer: SideMenu(),
      appBar: AppBar(
        centerTitle: true,
        //automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
        title: Text(
          'D P C G',
          style: TextStyle(
            fontSize: 20,
          ),
        ),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: SafeArea(
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Expanded(
                flex: 1,
                child: WWidget(
                  deglaPalmsWeatherData: widget.dPWeather,
                ),
              ),
              Expanded(
                flex: 1,
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    Expanded(
                      flex: 2,
                      child: Row(
                        children: [
                          Expanded(
                            flex: 1,
                            child: MWidget(),
                          ),
                          Expanded(
                            flex: 1,
                            child: SWidget(),
                          )
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                    Expanded(
                      flex: 2,
                      child: Row(
                        children: [
                          Expanded(
                            flex: 1,
                            child: IWidget(),
                          ),
                          Expanded(
                            flex: 1,
                            child: BWidget(),
                          )
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                    Expanded(
                      flex: 1,
                      child: SoonWidget(),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              DCCR(),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
      /////////////////////////////////
      //// Displaying AdMob Banner ////
      /////////////////////////////////
      bottomNavigationBar: Container(
        height: bannerHeight,
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  void deactivate() {
    super.deactivate();
    SystemChannels.platform.invokeMethod('SystemNavigator.pop');
  }
}
```

And this is **loading screen** code

```
import 'package:dpcg/main.dart';
import 'package:dpcg/main/constants.dart';
import 'package:firebase_messaging/firebase_messaging.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_spinkit/flutter_spinkit.dart';
import 'package:dpcg/main/home.dart';
import 'package:splashscreen/splashscreen.dart';
import 'package:firebase_admob/firebase_admob.dart';
import 'dart:io';

class LoadingScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _LoadingScreenState createState() => _LoadingScreenState();
}

class _LoadingScreenState extends State<LoadingScreen> {

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    ////////// Getting AdMob info
    FirebaseAdMob.instance
        .initialize(appId: 'ca-app-pub-AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA');
    ///////// Checking Required Data
    getAllInfo();
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////
    FirebaseMessaging firebaseMessaging = new FirebaseMessaging();
    firebaseMessaging.subscribeToTopic('DPNews');
  }


  getAllInfo() async {
    var weatherData = await WeatherNetworking().getData();

    Navigator.push(
      context,
      MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (context) {
          return MainHome(
            deglaPalmsWeather: weatherData,
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
              child: Image(
                image: AssetImage('images/dpcg.png'),
                fit: BoxFit.contain,
              ),
            ),
            Text(
              'Welcome \nD P C G\n\n',
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              style: TextStyle(
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                fontSize: 20.0,
                color: kMainColour,
              ),
            ),
            SpinKitWave(
              color: kMainColour,
              size: 100,
              duration: Duration(seconds: 5),
            ),
            Text(
              '\nMake sure you have internet connection',
              style: TextStyle(
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                fontSize: 10.0,
                color: kMainColour,
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

So what I should fix in my code?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try using a `FutureBuilder`.

Comment: @Andrej Could you explain more I googled it but couldn't find how to make it work for me

Comment: ```FutureBuilder(future: yourAd.load(), builder: (context, snapshot){
If (!snapshot.hasData){
return YourLoadingScreen;
} 

yourAd.show()
return YourWidgets;
},)```

Comment: @Andrej Thanks for concern, but I'm confused, your code should be add in loadingscreen.dart file so it will load Ad before loading screen and show it before loading screen or before home screen, I'm lost here, If you can simplified it as question answer I would be thankful